# reading a graph from a .data file

Tags: java, graph

Could someone clarify how this section of code inputs data onto a graph..
What kind of a file is .data?

```
public class DepthFirst {
static int numNodes;
static GraphNode nodes[];

  ...........
  ...........



public static void readGraph() throws IOException {
    File input = new File("digraph.data");
    Scanner digraph = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\D+");

            //if file is not empty
    if (digraph.hasNext()) {
        int nodeNum;
        numNodes = digraph.nextInt(); //System.out.println(numNodes);
        nodes = new GraphNode[numNodes];
        while (digraph.hasNext()) {
            nodeNum = digraph.nextInt();
            nodes[nodeNum] = new GraphNode(nodeNum, digraph.nextInt());
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes[nodeNum].getDegree(); i++) 
                nodes[nodeNum].setAdjListIndex(digraph.nextInt(), i); 
        } 
    }
    else return; 
}
```

Cheers 
Job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is in all likelihood just a plain old text file. The `.data` extension has no particular meaning.

Open it in any text editor, such as Notepad or Wordpad if you're running Windows. It should be pretty readable.

From what I can tell:

The file consists of a bunch of integers, separated by, well, anything that's not in the range 0-9 (which is what `\\D+` means, it's a regular expression, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more), probably whitespace.

The first entry is the number of nodes. Followed by all the nodes.

For each node, there is a node index, followed by its degree, followed by the indices of connected vertices (count = degree).

For more details on how exactly the graph is constructed, we'll need more details about what `GraphNode` looks like, but once you read a decent Java book or take a decent programming course in Java, it should be pretty clear.